# Difference-in-differences with two policies

Tags: difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

Can I use the general DiD approach with two policy variables (i.e., two treatments) as below?

```
xtreg outcome i.policy_1 i.policy_2 i.year, fe vce(cluster id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post doesn't say what type of data you're working with or what these treatments actually represent. But, in general, if the specifics of your study meet the requirements of the 'generalized' difference-in-differences estimator, then this approach may accommodate two policy dummies to represent the different treatments. Depending upon the circumstances, you may even suspect a synergy *between* the two treatments, in which case it is permissible to interact the two policy variables.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am working with micro survey data. The two treatments represent receiving benefits from two social safety nets. May you please advise on the requirements of the generalized difference-in-differences estimator? Kindly note that a respondent can be receiving benefits from one social safety net, both social safety nets, or none. But I did not combine the two treatments into one because I wanted to estimate the effect of each. Thank you again.